# Large user coordinates in SVG

Tags: svg, graphics, coordinates

I cannot get coordinate systems with large values to work. The renderer seems to just treat them as pixel values. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" 
    width="100%" height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 50000 50000" 
    >
    <circle  cx="25000"  cy="25000" r="10px" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

This uses a user coordinate system of a 50000 x 50000 square in the center of which should be a red dot, but no dot appears.

Comment: Works for me on Firefox on a Mac. It's really really tiny though.

Comment: @RobertLongson You are right. Apparently it is not respecting the radius dimension as "10px", but is treating it as just "10" (in the user coordinate system). Is there a way to make the circle absolutely 10px ?

Comment: That's how SVG works. The clue is in the **S** of SVG.